# Submit form and get selected data from dropdownlist in a servlet

Tags: servlets

i have a doPost() method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    LOGGER.debug("Form Submitted with username: " + request.getAttribute("username"));
}
```

and my JSP

```
<select name="username" onchange="this.from.submit();">
  <c:forEach var="ovr" items='${overrides}'>
    <option value="${ovr.overrideId}">${ovr.userId}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

there's nothing logged, this suggests the form wasn't submitted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onchange says `this.from.submit()` and not `this.form.submit()`

Comment: You would get more people helping you if accepted some of the answers.